# Sending data from processing back to arduino

Tags: java, arduino, processing, twitter4j

We have a program that counts the number of tweets for yes and no relating to the brexit refenrendum. Here's a link to a pastebin since I couldn't get the code to properly format: http://pastebin.com/G3v02KjF

Anyway, we're sending information from processing to the arduino to get the tweets using the Twitter4j library. We've counted the tweets and received a number that we want to be the angle of a servo. However, we can't figure out how to send this number back to arduino so we can control the servo.

How would we go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Serial library reference](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/) and the [write()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_write_.html) function in particular.

Since you're passing a single value, the angle (from 0 to 180) this integer value can be send as a single byte. For example in the `calculateAngle()` function you can send it to arduino:

```
if(myPort != null) myPort.write((int)angle);
```

(Bare in mind, casting the float value to an integer will floor/round the value down)

On the Arduino side, you simply need to read the value back, if there is at least one byte available. It's a good idea to [constrain()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Constrain) the value, just in case there are errors (and you wouldn't want to use invalid servo positions)

```
if(Serial.available() > 0){
  int angle = constrain(Serial.read(),0,180);
  myservo.write(angle);
}
```

Be sure to checkout the following examples:

- Processing > Examples > Libraries > serial > **SimpleWrite** (use the Arduino code provided at the bottom of the Processing sketch)
- Arduino > Examples > 04.Communication > **SerialEvent**